# Roundcube shows sender in Sent folder

Tags: roundcube

The roundcube v.0.7.4 webmail sent folder always shows in a column the sender when the recipient would be much more interesting. I read a few posts about this problem, but still no one works for me. I recently "upgrade" from 0.5 to 0.7 and I don't remember if that problems was there in 0.5.

*Update*

Propably I have enough if I can show both, sender and receiver address in all views. Where can I change/patch this ?

Comment: You should think to upgrade in version 1.0 as all the older have some security issues... and the problem will be maybe solved. And on my 1.0, the receipt is displayed

Comment: Yes, I will do ASAP but I have concerned about PHP ver. with other software running on same server.